# Terminal panel color different than other

Tags: pantheon-terminal, themes

I donẗ know why, but Terminal panel color is from dark theme, but everything else follow standard gray/silver color. How to fix this?

edit: I found that Videos media player is also dark. Is elementary OS theme broken?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, probably it's chosen where it was deemed appropriate. For example a darker border around a Video is less "distracting". Daniel Foré is working on a light theme for Terminal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOAlqsA0XF0

Not sure why such choices aren't covered in the Human Interface Guidelines
https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines